Standard library not detected in my custom Clang Tool
I have the following code (Want to Develop a CXX refactoring tool)
using namespace clang;

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

    static llvm::cl::OptionCategory KsaiToolOptions("my_tool optoins");
    static llvm::cl::extrahelp CommonHelp(clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser::HelpMessage);
    static llvm::cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore Help Text .. \n");

    std::string Error;
    auto CompilationDatabase = clang::tooling::JSONCompilationDatabase::loadFromFile(
         "compile_commands.json", Error, tooling::JSONCommandLineSyntax::AutoDetect);
    if (not Error.empty() and not CompilationDatabase) {
        llvm::outs() << "CompilationDatabase Error:" << Error << "\n";
    }

    auto Parser = clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, KsaiToolOptions);
    if (not Parser) {
        llvm::errs() << Parser.takeError();
        return 1;
    }
    auto Tool = clang::tooling::ClangTool(*CompilationDatabase, Parser->getSourcePathList());

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Refactor>> Refactors;
    Refactors.emplace_back(std::move(std::make_unique<KsaiRefactor::MoveDeclarationsToCppFile>()));
    for (auto &Refactor : Refactors) {
        if (Tool.run(tooling::newFrontendActionFactory(&Refactor->mFinder).get()) != 0) {
            llvm::outs() << "Failure Tooling\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

But when I try to run it, it cannot find the CXX headers,
C:/Users/sansk/OneDrive/Desktop/ksai_shree/include\include.hxx:2:10: fatal error: 
      'cstdio' file not found
    2 | #include <cstdio>
      |          ^~~~~~~~

It is super frustrating. I've tried to manually include the CXX headers on windows, but it will have an error at __pragma(pack(pop)), saying pop is not defined.
This is how I did that

"-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\include";

std::string CStandardLibraryPath = "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.22621.0\\ucrt";

std::string CStandardLibraryPathShared = "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.22621.0\\shared";

std::string CStandardLibraryPathUm = "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.22621.0\\um";

std::string CStandardLibraryPathWinRT = "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.22621.0\\winrt";

std::string DeclareWin32 = "-D_WIN32";

Tool.appendArgumentsAdjuster(tooling::getInsertArgumentAdjuster(CXXStandardLibraryPath.c_str()));

Tool.appendArgumentsAdjuster(tooling::getInsertArgumentAdjuster(CStandardLibraryPath.c_str()));

Tool.appendArgumentsAdjuster(tooling::getInsertArgumentAdjuster(CStandardLibraryPathShared.c_str()));

Tool.appendArgumentsAdjuster(tooling::getInsertArgumentAdjuster(CStandardLibraryPathUm.c_str()));

Tool.appendArgumentsAdjuster(tooling::getInsertArgumentAdjuster(CStandardLibraryPathWinRT.c_str()));

Tool.appendArgumentsAdjuster(tooling::getInsertArgumentAdjuster(DeclareWin32.c_str()));


